# How can I exclude computed columns from a history table in SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with computed column using scalar function and I'm interested to use temporal table in SQL Server 2019.

I'm unable to change the column - how can I get the benefits from that feature?

Some suggestions:

1. Do not include computed column in history table at all
2. Create a fixed column in history table with the same name of the computed column

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create history table with same same column list as transaction table but instead of computed column you will create a regular column with same datatype.

Then copy the data to history table with `insert into select * from` statement.

Please check the below example out:

Create table with computed column:

```
create table sales(productid int, quantity int, price int, totalprice as quantity * price);
```

Insert data into table with computed column:

```
 insert into sales (productid,quantity,price)values(1,100,10);
 insert into sales (productid,quantity,price)values(2,10,12);
 insert into sales (productid,quantity,price)values(1,50,100);
```

Output:

| productid | quantity | price | totalprice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 10 | 1000 |
| 2 | 10 | 12 | 120 |
| 1 | 50 | 100 | 5000 |

Create history table without any computed column.

```
 create table saleshistory(productid int, quantity int, price int, totalprice int);
```

Insert data into history table without computed column from the transaction table with computed column.

```
 insert into saleshistory select * from sales;
```

Select data from history table:

```
 select * from saleshistory;
```

Output:

| productid | quantity | price | totalprice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 10 | 1000 |
| 2 | 10 | 12 | 120 |
| 1 | 50 | 100 | 5000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=382e13f582aa382d9b152a2e1079dfb3)*

Comment: thanks for your answer , but the main problem is that , the computed column depends on a scalar function from another table.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you don't have any system versioned tables created so far on a table that includes a computed column.

The standard implementation is to simply roll your own history table instead of letting SqlServer create it for you.

It is a requirement of `temporal tables` for the history table schema to match the primary table - you *cannot* choose to omit columns.

When you set up the system versioning however, just script out your primary table and replace the computed column with the correct data type, then to set up system versioning on a table you would do

```
alter table dbo.MyTable add
    ValidFrom datetime2 generated always as row start hidden constraint DF_MyTableSysStart default sysutcdatetime(),
    ValidTo datetime2 generated always as row end hidden constraint DF_MyTableSysEnd default convert(datetime2, '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'),
    period for system_time (ValidFrom,ValidTo);

alter table MyTable set (system_versioning = on (history_table = history.MyTable));
```

Here as an example you have already created the temporal table with the same name in the schema `history`